# How to crop specific shape from photo using C# in UWP?

Tags: c#, image-processing, uwp

I need to crop specific shape which is defined in .png image (transparent background and white shape on top of that) from photo in UWP application.

Only code I found was for cropping shapes like circle or square, and I need to crop custom shapes which are created as png images which is nowhere in any docs or on forums, so there is no code I could present to you that would work like that.

To be even more specific I need function which receives two png files, one is photo and second is shape which should be cropped from the photo, and then that cropped part with transparent background is saved to specified location as .png file

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what the problem is and what you have tried so far - be specific about what you can't get to work.

Comment: Only code i found was for cropping shapes like circle or square, and i need to crop custom shapes which are created as png images which is nowhere in any docs or on forums, so there is no code I could present to you that would work like that. To be even more specific i need function which receives two png files, one is photo and second is shape which should be cropped from the photo, and then that cropped part with transparent background is saved to specified location as png file

Comment: I'm not saying you haven't spent time looking for a solution, but so far you've only showed that you have looked for a copy-pastable solution rather than show an attempt at solving it. Making an attempt usually attracts more interest to help. Let me suggest a start: break down the problem to a very simple example. Try cropping a 2x2 px image (hint: you're working with a raster image, so you need to inspect each pixel in the shape)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I found the solution using `SixLabors.ImageSharp` nuget package (both images should be same size).

```cs
private static async Task<string> CropShapeFromImage(string sourceImagePath, string maskImagePath)
{
    using var sourceImage = Image.Load<Rgba32>(sourceImagePath);

    var outputImage = new Image<Rgba32>(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);

    // Some workaround for acces deined to file error
    var maskFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(maskImagePath);
    var tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

    var tempMaskFile = await maskFile.CopyAsync(tempFolder, maskFile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using var maskImage = Image.Load<Rgba32>(tempMaskFile.Path);

    // Ensure that the source image and mask image have the same dimensions
    var width = Math.Min(sourceImage.Width, maskImage.Width);
    var height = Math.Min(sourceImage.Height, maskImage.Height);

    // Iterate over each pixel and apply the mask
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // Verify that the coordinates are within the valid range
            if (x >= sourceImage.Width || y >= sourceImage.Height || x >= maskImage.Width || y >= maskImage.Height) continue;
            var maskPixel = maskImage[x, y];

            // Set the alpha channel of the output image based on the mask
            outputImage[x, y] = new Rgba32(sourceImage[x, y].R, sourceImage[x, y].G, sourceImage[x, y].B, maskPixel.A);
        }
    }

    // Save the output image to a file with a transparent background
    var outputImagePath = Path.Combine(tempFolder.Path, "output.png");
    await outputImage.SaveAsync(outputImagePath);

    return outputImagePath;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting is, that you lose the alpha value from the original image.